# What is the probability that 10 participants answer the same in a multiple choice questionnaire?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a questionnaire of 26 questions each with 4 possible options (there is no correct answer). There are 30 participants and 10 of them answered the exact same choices. What is the probability of this happening ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: there is no correct answer to the questions as in, this is not an exam/test. This was a survey. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: I think this is going to involve quite large numbers. There are $4^{26}$ different answer orders, so the probability of a match is $\frac{1}{4^{26}}$. Also, I think the problem could be phrased better. Are there any restrictions for the other 20 participants? If we consider $n=$the largest subset of perticipants that answered the same, are we asking for the probability of $n=10$ ? Rembember that there could be also smaller subsets of participants, for some different set of answers. There can be also two subsets with size $10$...

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for the questions. There are no restrictions on any other participants and yes there might be cases where a smaller subset of participants which had the same answers to a different set of questions, but I am not interested in that. These 10 participants was the largest subset (I have already checked).

Comment: I would approach this by considering a Bernoulli random variable with a probability $p = \frac{1}{4^{26}}$. There are 30 trials and 10 successes are recorded. The probability for that would be (according to Binomial distribution)
$$
{30 \choose{10}} p^{10} (1-p)^{20}
$$
But we need to modify this slightly, becase there are still $4^{26}= \frac{1}{p}$ options to choose from! So I think the answer should be
$$
{30 \choose{10}} p^{10} (1-p)^{20} \times \frac{1}{p} = {30 \choose{10}} p^{9} (1-p)^{20}
$$
with $p=\frac{1}{4^{26}}$

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks for the answer. Also, a slight modification but if a question had more than 4 options how does that affect this ? So lets say that one question has 5 options and another has 6 while the remaining 28 have 4 each.

Comment: Then you would have to recalculate the total number of different questionnaire answers:
$$
4^{\text{# of questions with 4 options}} \times 5^{\text{# of questions with 5 options}} \times \text{ etc ...}
$$

Comment: Thanks @MattiP. Assuming 24 questions with 4 options, 1 with 5 and 1 with 6: this would give me:     $$ p = \frac{1}{4^{24}} \times \frac{1}{5^1} \times \frac{1}{6^1}$$ and the probability of success and failure remains the same ?

Comment: Yeah, just plug in the value of $p$ and you would get the result. But I can't promise that my approach was correct, it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Sure. I will wait to see if someone else comments and offers some insight or help. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the numerical answer is quite minuscule, about
$$
\approx 10^{-136}
$$
Second "BTW": We never assumed that the answers are evenly distributed! If one of the questions was, for example: "What year is it now?", it's likely that all 30 would answer the same ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also for your second point, yes I am aware of this issue that certain options could have been more likely. But I am assuming for the time being that for each question the choices were all equally likely.

Comment: @DanielMathias : I am explicitly assuming that every choice/option for a question was equally likely. What I would like to know is: given that each choice was equally likely: what is the probability that 10 out of 30 participants ended up with the same answers. This would have to be quite small as Matti's comments have also shown.

Comment: @AyushJoshi What happens if 8 people all choose the exact same answers, 2 people choose 25 of the same answers as the original 8, but one different one, and they happen to choose the same answers as each other. Example, 8 people choose option 1 for all 26 answer. Two people choose option 1 for the first 25 answers, and option 2 for the 26th answer. Does this count as 10 people choosing the same answers?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe No, the 2 people who have 25 of the same answers as the 8 and one different (but same as each other) are not counter and in this instance only 8 people are considered. Essentially, I am looking at the largest group of people who answered the same in my questionnaire study.

Comment: @AyushJoshi so what if 11 people all answer exactly the same? Does that still count?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe That is exactly what I am after, the probability that n number of people answered exactly the same. In my case that n happens to be 10. Also, there could be other groups of people who answer different set of identical answers but their number is smaller than 10 in my problem case and I am not concerned about them. There is a theoretical possibility that 2 groups of the same size answer different set of identical questions but this has not happened in my questionnaire.

Comment: @AyushJoshi so, if 11 people all answer exactly the same, then it would not count?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe here is some more context: in this study 10 of the participants all answered exactly the same (this is the largest group size of identical answers) and I am interested in finding the probability of something so unlikely happening. So this also means that any other group of identical answers in my study is smaller than 10. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AyushJoshi Here is my reason for being so specific. The problem you are describing is not at all easy to answer. The other commenters have given answers that are likely close approximations of the actual answer, but this particular problem is no longer a Bernoulli trial. So, if you are looking for a more accurate answer, I am asking you to be very specific about the details of what outcomes are acceptable and what outcomes are unacceptable. Example: if the largest group has exactly 11 members, and every other group has less than 10, does this still satisfy your conditions?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Thank you for the taking the time and I agree with your statement that this is a tough problem. Yes: the largest group has 11 members and every other group has less than 10, this satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Another point is that the natural question to ask is, what is the probability that at least 10 people answered all the questions the same? In the sense of, if I flip a coin 100 times and get 78 heads, then the question to ask --in terms of understanding "how rare was that for a fair coin?" -- is "What is the probability of 78 or more heads in 100 tosses?" not the prob. of exactly 78 heads, since e.g. exactly 50 heads is fairly unlikely too ...

Comment: @Ned I see your point yet in my instance this particular event 'has happened' and I am trying to find its odds 'after the fact'. Yes I can ask the question 'what is the probability that at least 10 participants' got the same answers but this will include the probability of more than 10 getting the right answers too (which I am not interested in for my study). They are two separate questions both valid in their own sense.

Comment: @AyushJoshi you need to be a bit careful when you say this particular event 'has happened'. Finding the odds of something 'after the fact' means that you already know it happened with 100% certainty. So, the probability that something you know happened actually happened is always 100%, regardless of how improbable it would ordinarily be. This is known as conditional probability. In math notation, $P(A|A) = 1$. This says, the probability that event A occurs given that event A occurs is 100%.

Comment: Alternately, if you are saying, "what is the probability it will happen again?" that is a completely different question, and there are several ways of determining it. Perhaps you use the results from known survey as a sample and modify your assumptions about how respondents will answer. This will allow you to recalculate the probability using Bayesian analysis. Alternately, you can assume that the survey never took place, in which case my solution below is a correct answer.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe you are right that my wording above was not precise at all, incorrect rather! I am assuming that the survey did not happen. Also, the Bayesian analysis approach sounds interesting (using the prior knowledge from my current experiment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution. It is not at all easy to calculate. You would likely need to write a program in a statistics language like R or Mathematica to get the solution.

Let $A$ be the set of all possible answers to a single survey. As others have mentioned, $|A| = 4^{26}$. Among answers chosen by the 30 participants, we can have exactly 1 element of $A$ repeated 30 times, or as many as 21 elements of $A$, one with repetition 10 and the others with repetition 1 each. This allows us to partition the set of outcomes for the 30 participants that meet the requirements you set so that each case is disjoint and we can apply the addition principle.

First, we need to sum over all possible numbers of distinct answer sets: $k=1$ to $21$.
Then, we need to choose solutions to a Diophantine equation such that $$C_k = \left\{(a_1, \cdots, a_k)\mid \forall i: a_i \in \mathbb{Z}, \sum_{i=1}^k a_i = 30, a_1\ge 10, 1\le a_2 < 10, \forall i>2: 1\le a_i \le a_{i-1} \right\}$$
Each $k$-tuple in $C_k$ represents a selection of $k$ distinct answers to the surveys where each $a_i$ represents a multiplicity of the number of respondents who answered according to the chosen distinct survey response (the multiplicities are decreasing to avoid the same set of multiplicities multiple times), so the number of possible ways to distribute the survey results among the 30 participants is:

$$\dfrac{30!}{\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k a_i!}$$

And the number of ways to choose the distinct survey results:

$$\dbinom{|A|}{k}$$

And because each of the $k$ distinct survey results can correspond to any of the $k$ $a_i$ values, we need to permute the $a_i$'s (but take multiplicities into account). So, for each $k$-tuple, you need to know the multiplicities of each of the values represented by the $a_i$'s. For each $c \in C_k$, let $M(c)$ be the multiset of the $k$-tuple (example, $M(28,1,1)$ is the multiset $\{1\cdot 2, 28\cdot 1\}$). So, let $\pi(M(c))$ be the number of multiset permutations of the multiset of $c$ (Example: $\pi(M(28,1,1)) = \dfrac{3!}{2!1!}$).

So, putting this all together:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{21} \dfrac{\dbinom{|A|}{k}}{|A|^{30}}\left( \sum_{(a_1,\cdots, a_k) \in C_k} \dfrac{30!}{\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^k a_i!}\pi(M(a_1,\cdots, a_k)) \right)$$